# Altium BGA fanout problem

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, altium, fan

I have a problem with Altium fanout.

I can not use fanout with my BGA processor (AM335x,) but fanout is working on DDR3 and eMMC.

I did the same things with DDR3 and the processor but fanout for the processor did not work.

You can see the screenshot of my problem.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: How do you plan to do the fan-out? What did you try and what failed? How is your planned PCB stack-up and via style?

Comment: Check your design rules. The vias likely don't fit between the BGA pads.